# Is it permissible to have a picture without the eye visible?

Tags: fiqh, image

I know that pictures are not allowed in homes. But somebody told me it is permissible to hang a picture if you cannot see the eyes of the being. Anybody knows if that is true?

The specific picture in question is one of a cat but only its back is visible?

Answer (score 2):

The image that should erase everything that was in the image of a human being or an animal, it must obliterate her face only, and enough blur her face for the rest of her body, while the images of trees, stones, mountains, sun, moon, and stars, and so on, this is not okay, and should not be smudge. the image of an eye only or face only: this is not the thing, because it is not in, that's part of it, not image
**

> Narrated 'A’ishah: I stuffed for the Prophet (Peace and blessings be
>   upon him) a pillow decorated with pictures (of animals) which looked
>   like a Namruqah (i.e. a small cushion). He came and stood among the
>   people with excitement apparent on his face. I said, "O Allah's
>   Apostle! What is wrong?" He said, "What is this pillow?" I said, "I
>   have prepared this pillow for you, so that you may recline on it." He
>   said, "Don't you know that angels do not enter a house wherein there
>   are pictures; and whoever makes a picture will be punished on the Day
>   of Resurrection and will be asked to give life to (what he has
>   created)?" [Bukhari 4:47]

**

Comment: sorry but I dont understand, I read it several times. So it is okay if there is a cat, but the face must me blurred, do I understand you right?